# Formatting the string by substitute the same substring

Tags: go

I have a code which looks like:

```
const query = `select * 
               from %s.dbo.table1 
               join %s.dbo.table2
                 on ....
               join %s.dbo.table3
                 on ....
               join %s.dbo.table4
                 on ....`

 fmt.Sprintf(query, dbName, dbName, dbName, dbName)
```

I just create a SQL query by inserting the database name to all `%s` occurrences.  Is the a better way to do it without repeating `dbName` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `%[1]s`:

```
const query = `select * 
           from %[1]s.dbo.table1 
           join %[1]s.dbo.table2
             on ....
           join %[1]s.dbo.table3
             on ....
           join %[1]s.dbo.table4
             on ....`
q := fmt.Sprintf(query, dbName)
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/2DDiGfxLPk.

Documentation: https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/.

> For example,
>
> ```
> fmt.Sprintf("%[2]d %[1]d\n", 11, 22)
> ```
>
> will yield "22 11", while
>
> ```
> fmt.Sprintf("%[3]*.[2]*[1]f", 12.0, 2, 6)
> ```
>
> equivalent to
>
> ```
> fmt.Sprintf("%6.2f", 12.0)
> ```
>
> will yield " 12.00". (…)